How to center-align the TextureRect used with set_drag_preview()?
I use the following code to display a dragged item preview:
func _get_drag_data(at_position: Vector2) -> Variant:
    var drag_preview := TextureRect.new()
    drag_preview.expand_mode = TextureRect.EXPAND_IGNORE_SIZE
    drag_preview.texture = icon_texture_rect.texture
    drag_preview.custom_minimum_size = Vector2(80, 80)
    drag_preview.modulate = Color(1, 1, 1, 0.75)
    set_drag_preview(drag_preview)
    # return this item slot as the thing to be dragged
    return self

It works, but the dragged rectangle is being dragged by its top-left corner, while I’d like the mouse pointer to drag its middle:

Does anybody please have a suggestion on how to implement this?
I have not found a suitable method in TextureRect and Control docs.

My question has been answered in the Godot forum:
func _get_drag_data(at_position: Vector2) -> Variant:
    var drag_preview := Control.new()
    var texture_rect := TextureRect.new()
    texture_rect.modulate = Color(1, 1, 1, 0.75)
    texture_rect.expand_mode = TextureRect.EXPAND_IGNORE_SIZE
    texture_rect.texture = icon_texture_rect.texture
    texture_rect.custom_minimum_size = Vector2(80, 80)
    # center-align the texture_rect, so that mouse pointer is in its middle
    texture_rect.position = -0.5 * texture_rect.custom_minimum_size
    drag_preview.add_child(texture_rect)
    set_drag_preview(drag_preview)
    # return this item slot as the thing to be dragged
    return self

